# Is a wildcard in generics an object or just the data of the object?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a node.

```
Node<T> someNode;
```

And this someNode has data fields, prev, next, and data,
where prev and next are integers, and data is of whatever type T.

If I write a method, say something like:

```
public boolean addNodeToList(T e) {

}
```

Does T e, in the method's parameter, point to the someNode itself,
or just someNode.data?

Comment: Not clear. Provide more code.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to understand type parameters by thinking about `List<T>` where `T` can be a `String`, for example.

Comment: but 'List' itself is not type of 'String'. It does make sense that 'String' is a type of 'Object'. But 'Node<String> stringNode' will only hold data values of type 'String'. But just doing 'print(stringNode);' will only print the address of the 'stringNode' inside the JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `T` in `public boolean addNodeToList(T e)` would be the same type as the `T` in `Node<T> somedata` assuming `Node<T>` was defined as:

```
class Node<T> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addNodeToList(T e){
        list.add(e);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
Node<String> someData = new Node<>();
someData.addToList("string1");
someData.addToList("string2");
```

Now if you wanted to do a parent/child node then you'd define `Node` like this:

```
class Node<T> {
    private List<Node<T>> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public T data;

    public boolean addChildNode(Node<T> child){
        children.add(child);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
Node<String> parent = new Node();
parent.data = "string1";

Node<String> child = new Node();
child.data = "string2";
parent.addChildNode(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

It points to whatever somebody passed into that method, though that data must be of type `T`.  You can't pass in a `Node<T>` to that method, though presumably you can pass in the data of that node -- but the `T` doesn't have to come from `someNode.data`.